# Simple form post in python not producing same results as in HTML

Tags: python, html, forms

This very simple HTML code (well the URL is ugly, but otherwise it is simple) does a form post.  If you type, for example, "hi" into the textarea and hit Submit, it shows the page you would expect: something along the lines of not being able to find a package with tracking number "hi".

```
<form action="http://www.chronopost.fr/transport-express/livraison-colis/accueil/suivi?appid=9680_718&amp;appparams=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chronopost.fr%3A54711%2Fwebclipping%2Fservlet%2Fwebclip%3Fjahia_url_web_clipping%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54702%2Fexpedier%2FinputLTNumbers.do&amp;resetAppSession=true#field_9680" method="post">
<textarea name="chronoNumbers"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If I try to do the equivalent in python:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import urllib
import urllib2

url = "http://www.chronopost.fr/transport-express/livraison-colis/accueil/suivi?appid=9680_718&amp;appparams=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chronopost.fr%3A54711%2Fwebclipping%2Fservlet%2Fwebclip%3Fjahia_url_web_clipping%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54702%2Fexpedier%2FinputLTNumbers.do&amp;resetAppSession=true#field_9680"
values = {"chronoNumbers": "hi"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_page = response.read()
with open("outfile.html", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(the_page)
```

The resulting page instead says "Exception loading application data".  I get the same behavior when I use the "requests" package instead of "urllib".

Does anybody know why the result is different?

Comment: Entering the URL in a browser (GET) or using curl to send a POST also results in "Exception loading application data". Maybe you need to be logged in (cookies) or set the correct referral in your request?

Comment: I tried my simple HTML snippet in an incognito window, and it still worked.  So I don't think either of the pages require any cookies to be set.